# How to do show the product using clistview in yii framework

Tags: yii

I'm using this code then clearly explain that list view please

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'itemView' => '/site/listproduct',
    ));
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you,
In controller,

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->order="id DESC";
    $viewList=new CActiveDataProvider('Business',array('criteria'  => $criteria));
```

and in view

```
 <?
                    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
                        'id'=>'view-listing',
                        'dataProvider'=>$viewList,
                        'itemView'=>'_view',   // refers to the partial view named '_post'
                        'itemsTagName'=>'ul',
                        'itemsCssClass'=>'listingcontent clearfix',
                        'htmlOptions' => array('class' => ''),
                        'enablePagination'=>true,
                        'pagerCssClass'=>'pagination',
                        'pager'=>array(
                            'header'=>'',
                            'selectedPageCssClass'=>'active',
                            'prevPageLabel'=>'<<',
                            'nextPageLabel'=>'>>',
                            'cssFile'=>false,
                            'firstPageLabel'=>'<',
                            'lastPageLabel'=>'>',
                            'htmlOptions'=>array(
                                'class'=>'pagination',
                                'style'=>'',
                            ),      
                        ),
                    )); ?>
```

and in _view

```
<?=$data->id?>
```

Comment: does this helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="row"> 
 <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView',array(
          'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
         'itemView' => '_list',
       )); ?>
 </div>
```

In _list.php:

```
<div class="leftnav <?= $data->firstname ?></div>
<div class="leftnav <?= $data->lastname ?></div>
```

as per your requirment you can design in _list.php file.

CListView displays a list of data items in terms of a list. 
Check this link:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView

Comment: The display is done via the partial view named '_list'. This partial view will be rendered once for every data item.

Comment: Basically i used CListView for display product in e commerce portal with auto load

Comment: I have another doubt with java collection concept.what purpose of 'retain' method?

Comment: I know retainAll method, not 'retain' method.

Comment: The retainAll(Collection<?> c) method is used to retain only the elements in this Vector that are contained in the specified Collection. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Comment: Hi..guys...one doubt pls explain,what purpose and why do use wordpress and what is cms.....give me ans urgent...